# I want to know how to apply this complex function in my coding

Tags: c++

```
-((I (ArcCos[1/40 ((dOm - 4 I) - \[Tau])]/Sqrt[-((-2 dOm + 4 I) + \[Omega]) (4 I + \[Omega])] - ArcCos[1/dOm ((dOm + 4 I) - \[Omega])]/Sqrt[((2 dOm + 4 I) - \[Omega]) (-4 I + \[Omega])]))/(2 \[Pi]))
```

This is a convolution result from Mathemetica. I try to convert this function into my coding as a integration kernel, like this,

```
{
double sigma_PAM;
complex<double> ss1((dOm-dTau)/dOm, -4/dOm);
complex<double> ss2((16-2*dOm*dTau-dTau*dTau, 8*(dOm-dTau)));
complex<double> ss3((dOm-dTau)/dOm, 4/dOm);
complex<double> ss4((16-2*dOm*dTau-dTau*dTau, -8*(dOm-dTau)));
sigma1_PAM=real(-1i*(acos(ss1)/sqrt(ss2)-acos(ss3)/sqrt(ss4))/(2*3.14));
return  sigma1_PAM;
}
```

but it shows many error and, of course, doesn't work....

Comment: *"it shows many errors"*. which ones?

Comment: I don't understand your correspondence, you have `16` which doesn't appears in original formula, it has `1/40` that you don't have...

Comment: `1i` won't work without C++14 support and `using namespace std::complex_literals;`.

Comment: @Jarod42 oh sorry 1/40 is just 1/dOm i missed it, and 16 is result of multiplication in sqrt(). The error message is too long and i failed upload full text... I will post it later

Comment: @Evg Thank you, I try to do it

Comment: Aside: you don't need to declare variables at the top of a function, doing so is worse than declaring them at the point of use. Having said that, I'd just `return /* calculation */`